# Out-of-range value when converting dates separated by dots

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

How can I convert the following `VARCHAR(50)` data:

```
01.01.2020 06:10:15
```

to a DateTime?

Comment: (1) SQL doesn't have "objects".  Are you sure you are talking about databases?  (2) If so, what database are you using?

Comment: ANSI SQL has timestamp as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Comment: What does the first `01` refer to? Month or day?

Comment: @SalmanA has the correct answer, but I would recommend you to not use the type DATETIME for new work. "Use the time, date, datetime2 and datetimeoffset data types for new work." Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the dates are in dd.mm.yyyy format, you can use the [date and time style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles) #104 (German) that uses this exact format:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '13.01.2020 06:10:15')
-- The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '13.01.2020 06:10:15', 104)
-- 2020-01-13 06:10:15.000
```

Comment: I would use this as well. Style 104 is the only one that uses the format "dd.mm.yyyy".

Would also recommend to stop using DATETIME, new work should use "time, date, datetime2 and datetimeoffset data types": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below method:

```
 SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2017-08-25')
```

in place of the date under singled quotes you can place the variable name.

Comment: That answer is product specific (it's not "SQL", looks like T-SQL) - how do you know which DBMS product user2672844 is using?

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Code :

```
select convert(datetime, '01.01.2020 06:10:15', 104)
```

[Help Link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/)

Comment: I get also this error: The conversion to a DateTime data type resulted in an out-of-range DateTime value. Maybe the dots in the date are the problem

Comment: May be it is some other date that is causing the problem and not the one you posted in question.

Comment: The date time style "20" is wrong, that would be for "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss".
Check the documentation for correct date styles: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @AminGolmahalle I am sorry, but the code example you give is wrong, you can not use type 20 on '01.01.2020 06:10:15'.

Comment: @Jarle Bjørnbeth if learned help link.you see each number can select accordance with your result.20 just was sample.

Comment: @AminGolmahalle the sample is still wrong for that date format. Do not expect anyone to click a link to make the sample work correctly. It is also a risk that someone could copy & paste that into their system if this answer is accepted. That might be dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by this way

```
Declare @Str VARCHAR(50) = '01.01.2020 06:10:15'

Select CONVERT(date, REPLACE(@Str, '.', '/'), 103)
```